# OpenGL Framebuffer Copying

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to copy from one framebuffer to another framebuffer

here is my code:

I'm copying rects from back to front framebuffer

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rectangles->size; i++)
 {

   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, backFramebufferId);
   checkForGLError("back to front Binded read backFramebufferId...");
   glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);

  glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, frontFramebufferId);
  checkForGLError("back to front Binded write frontFramebufferId...");
  glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);

  sourcex1 = rectangles -> rectangles[i].srcX;
  sourcey1 = rectangles -> rectangles[i].srcY;
  int currDstX = rectangles -> rectangles[i].dstX;
  int currDstY = rectangles -> rectangles[i].dstY;
  int w = rectangles -> rectangles[i].width;
  int h = rectangles -> rectangles[i].height;


  glBlitFramebufferEXT(sourcex1,  sourcey1,
                     sourcex1 + w,  sourcey1 + h,
                     currDstX, currDstY,
                     currDstX + w,  currDstY + h,
                     GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
  checkForGLError("back to front glBlitFramebufferEXT...");

  glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
  glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

and then in this loop I'm copying whole front framebuffer in back framebufferbuffer

```
  glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, frontFramebufferId);
  checkForGLError("front to back Binded read frontFramebufferId...");
  glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);

  glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, backFramebufferId);
  checkForGLError("front to back Binded write backFramebufferId...");
  glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);

  glBlitFramebufferEXT(0,  0,
                  frameWidth,  frameHeight,
                  0, 0,
                  frameWidth,  frameHeight,
                  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
  checkForGLError("front to back glBlitFramebufferEXT...");

  glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
  glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);


 } // end of loop
```

I want to ask , is this code right or I have some mistake?

Comment: Well, is it working? Looks reasonable at first sight. If you have at least OpenGL 3.0 available, you should be able to use the core version instead of the EXT version of these calls.

Comment: sometimes it's cant copy fast from one to second framebuffer, and I see old frames.

Comment: As long as all the calls come from the same thread/context, and you make all the draw calls before the `glBlitFramebuffer()` call, the copy should contain all the results from those draw calls.

Comment: first I draw in framebuffer and then I'm calling glBlitFramebuffer.
All this calls are in same thread/context.

One more question , It's necessary to use glReadBuffer after glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT.. 
 and glDrawBuffer after glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT.. ???

Comment: No, if you never set them to a different value, the `ReadBuffer` and `DrawBuffer` calls are not needed. `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` is the default for both of them.